# Magento2: Set specific theme in layout XML - example checkout_index_index

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml

In Magento2 how to you update the theme in a layout XML?  In M1 you could set this in your layout;

```
<reference name=”root”>
<action method=”setTheme”><theme>custom-theme</theme></action>
</reference>
```

What is the correct syntax in M2?  For example, if you wanted to use the Luma checkout design on a custom theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your code as below:-

Create a **default.xml** file inside the layout folder and add this code

**1st Method:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sample123" template="Magento_Search::sample.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2nd Method:-**

Action node is deprecated, but you can use block arguments

```
<referenceBlock name="block_to_change">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[Module]::/path/to/template.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

**OR**

If you want to set specific theme for all action of controller you can add in controller

```
protected function _construct(){
   parent::_construct();
   Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
}
```

If you want to set for specific action then add below code at startup of action

```
 Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
        ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
        ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
```

Check following example:

```
public function loginAction()
{
   if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

   Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme

   $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. However that's how you set a block template, I'm wondering how you switch to an entirely new theme for a certain controller - like if you have a custom theme for your site, but want to switch to the Luma theme for the checkout

Comment: try the Updated Code ..... hope it will help u.

Comment: thanks for all the info - ill mark it as the answer, but in short the answer then is "you cant update the theme in XML"

Comment: You asked a question about Magento 2,  he gave you Magento 1 answers and you accepted the thing. Hmmm